# Partial fraction decomposition question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

How do I use partial fraction decomposition to split up the following:

$$\frac{1}{(1-q_1z)(1-q_2z)}$$

where both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are probabilities, and $q_1 = 1 - p_1$ and $q_2 = 1 - p_2$

The answer is supposed to be

$$\frac{q_1}{1-q_1z} - \frac{q_2}{1-q_2z}$$

but I only got as far as

$$\frac{1}{(1-q_1z)(1-q_2z)} = \frac{A}{1-q_1z} + \frac{B}{1-q_2z}$$
$$1 = A(1-q_2z) + B(1-q_1z)$$
$$A + B = 1$$
$$-Aq_2 -Bq_1 = 0$$

Solving the last 2 equations, I got

$$A = \frac{q_1}{q_1-q_2}$$
$$B = -\frac{q_2}{q_1-q_2}$$

Comment: The quoted answer looks wrong and your calculation is right.

Comment: Do you know anything about $p_1$ and $p_2$? Do they happen to satisfy $-p_1+p_2=1$?

Comment: @user170231 $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the parameters of 2 random variables.